# What is the documented range for TouchEvent#touches?

Tags: javascript, touch-event

I'm looking at the [TouchEvent#touches documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/touches) from MDN web docs, and the code sample provided only supports up to 3 touches.

```js
someElement.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
   // Invoke the appropriate handler depending on the
   // number of touch points.
   switch (e.touches.length) {
     case 1: handle_one_touch(e); break;
     case 2: handle_two_touches(e); break;
     case 3: handle_three_touches(e); break;
     default: console.log("Not supported"); break;
   }
}, false);
```

That being said, I'm pretty sure that there are 3+ finger touches, but I was wondering if there was a min/max range for these touches (e.g. can there be "0" touches in any scenario?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically speaking, the W3C standard for [TouchEvent](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/) does not define a maximum number of touches. Instead, the maximum is going to be the maximum number of consecutive touch points supported by the device's touch screen. In a virtual environment, this could presumably be infinite. Older devices seem to have been [less than 20 consecutive touch points](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/17606#:%7E:text=The%20iPhone%20supports%205%20simultaneous,nothing%20on%20a%2012th%20touch.), however this could have increased with more modern technology.

Technically speaking, the spec defines the `TouchList#length` property as an unsigned long, so the absolute maximum within the spec will be [4,294,967,295](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-unsigned-long) consecutive touch points:

```
interface TouchList {
    readonly    attribute unsigned long length;
    getter Touch? item (unsigned long index);
};
```

As for the minimum, the spec does not say that there must be at least one item in the list of active touches. However, if you are listening to the `touchstart` event, [then the received `TouchList` will always contain the touch which triggered the event](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#h3_attributes-2):

> `touches` of type *TouchList*, readonly
>
> a list of `Touch`es for every point of contact currently touching the surface.

and:

> `changedTouches` of type *TouchList*, readonly
>
> a list of `Touch`es for every point of contact which contributed to the event.
>
> For the `touchstart` event this must be a list of the touch points that just became active with the current event. [...]